# Htaccess - redirecionando o subdominio

Tags: php, htaccess

Eu tinha o subdominio "b2b".dominio.com.br e agora troquei os arquivos para o "catalogo".dominio.com.br

Quero uma regra htaccess

Que quando entrem no http://b2b.dominio.com.br/etcqlqr-coisa/qualquercoisa

Nao importa qual nivel esteja

Seja redirecionado para http://catalogo.dominio.com.br/etcqlqr-coisa/qualquercoisa

eu acho que se criar varias regras htaccess uma para cada nivel possivel de pasta resolveria, so que eu nao sei a primeira, pra multiplicar

http://b2b.cellsystem.com.br/18-cabeamento

tem que ir para
http://catalogo.cellsystem.com.br/18-cabeamento

assim como
http://b2b.cellsystem.com.br/telecomunicacao/2-connection-cable-rpm-113-612745m.html

para
http://catalogo.cellsystem.com.br/telecomunicacao/2-connection-cable-rpm-113-612745m.html

aqui ta a regra que acho que é o caminho

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^b2b.cellsystem.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://catalogo.cellsystem.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]

editado:

o suporte locaweb me passou isto http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Redirecionamento_301

vou tentar mas nao consegui ainda

editado:
nao deu

```
tentei redistribuir os arquivos index.php com o codigo em pastas com o nome de cada categoria e subcategoria, nao ta funcionando pq o produto é .html no final e nao index 

<?php
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$endereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: http://catalogo.cellsystem.com.br/{$endereco}");
```

**mas se alguem souber o htaccess agradeco**

vou tentar criar arquivo por arquivo html em quanto isso com redirect javascript

Comment: o mais perto que encontrei foi aqui
http://www.hostnet.com.br/wiki/index.php/Entenda_o_arquivo_.htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criar uma lógica nas páginas não seria a melhor prática para este caso.

Utilize o mecanismo do .htaccess para simplificar seu processo.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.b2b.cellsystem.com.br

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !b2b/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://catalogo.dominio.com.br/$1 [L]
```

Assim todo acesso que partir para b2b será redirecionado para catalogo, sem perder os parâmetros, seja em que nível for.

PS: cuidar para que não haja conflito entre as demais diretivas de seu .htacess

Answer (score 1):

boa tarde pessoal,
este código funcionou aqui:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / https://www.novodominio.com/
</IfModule>
```

Os parâmetros são mantidos